# GNU Parallel running Makefiles with different optimization levels

Tags: c, optimization, makefile, gnu-parallel

There is not a optimal -O level. My approach in order to find the fastest execution for my particular code is to compile the same code with usual optimization levels (i.e. -O0, -Ofast, -O1, -O2, -O3,-march=native) and check which flags produce me the fastest execution (with time).

So, there is a way to check all optimization levels (listed before) running a Makefile with each optimization (-O level)?

I think that Gnu Parallel could run the Makefile changing the -O level but I don't know how figure it out?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why setting `CCFLAGS` is not an option, again?

Comment: Could be an option but how edit CCFLAGS recursively to test all optimization levels using a unique Makefile? GnuParallel could be helpful but I dont know how achieve this task efficiently.

Comment: `for flag in -O0 -Ofast -O1 -O2 -O3 -march=native; do make CFLAGS+="$flag"; done`?

Comment: The `time` command is not a very good indicator of program's speed. http://www.ncsu.edu/hpc/Documents/sprofile.php

Comment: Try running `time` twice on the same program you might see it run faster the second time because it loaded from the hard drive the first time and it already resides in memory the second time.

Comment: You'll get much more information with a profiler.

Comment: `-Ofast -march=native` should give the fastest program eventhough you're disregarding "strict standard compliance" i.e. -ffast-math.  https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.2.0/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#Optimize-Options

Comment: @JeremiahDicharry: `-funroll-loops` is an important option that's only enabled with `-fprofile-use`.  (or manually), so don't just profile, but also let the compiler use the results.

Comment: Also let the compiler use the results?. Please @PeterCordes could you explain me the meaning of this sentece?

Comment: @Bruce_Warrior: updated my answer with profile-guided optimization, with links to clang and gcc manuals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use GNU Parallel to do multiple builds in parallel?  You'd need separate build directories at least, and a more complex build setup if you want to avoid copying the whole directory of source code.  If you try to do multiple separate builds in the same directory at the same time, some object files will be built with one set of `CFLAGS`, and others with others.

Use @Etan's loop suggestion:

```
NJOBS=$(getconf _NPROCESSORS_ONLN)  # adjust as desired
for flag in -O{0..3} -O{3,fast}" -march=native"; do
    make clean
    make -j"$NJOBS" CFLAGS+="$flag -fprofile-generate"
    ./a.out  # feed it some input that exercises different options and code paths
    make clean
    make -j"$NJOBS" CFLAGS+="$flag -fprofile-use"
    perf stat ./a.out | tee "perfstat$flag.txt"
done
```

Note the use of `make -j` for parallelism, rather than GNU parallel.  Also note the use of profile-guided optimization.  x264 has a build system with a `make fprofiled` target for building a PGO executable, which takes care of the build / run / rebuild cycle.  So it's possible, but IDK if it makes their Makefile messy.

You *could* use GNU parallel for the timing run of your code, but you'll get more consistent results if you do the timing run on an idle machine.

If you want to test how your code does when there are multiple copies of it running at the same time, competing for cache space and memory bandwidth (or even execution resources with hyperthreading), then test that with multiple copies of the *same* code, not having some runs competing with gcc, some with `-O0`, and some with `-O3`.

As far as optimization options, you will normally get the best results from gcc with [`-fprofile-generate` and `-fprofile-use`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#Optimize-Options) options.  Clang can also do [profile-guided optimization](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#profile-guided-optimization), using the same options, or using data from CPU perf counters.  (The manual describes using a tool to convert Linux `perf record` data into something Clang can use.)

Some gcc optimizations are only enabled with `-fprofile-use` (or manually, not with just `-O3`).  e.g. `-funroll-loops` can help in some tight loops.  Don't use for everything, because larger code size can lead to I-cache misses overall in the whole program, which outweigh gains from reducing loop overhead in some hot loops.

Comment: NCPUS=`getconf _NPROCESSORS_ONLN`

Comment: It can actually make sense to tell `make` to use more jobs than you have CPUs, to hide I/O latency.  Or to use fewer, if you have other stuff running.  But good suggestion for `getconf`.

Comment: Another alternative to check the code performance is with:
`valgrind —tool=callgrind ./a.out` and analyze it later with kcachegrind or callgrind_annotate checking the cycle estimation costs. 
However I don't know which option (perf or valgrind alternative) is recommended